# App crashs when I use Cookies in Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, cookies, nullpointerexception, webkit

I've got an app, where cookies get stored in a WebView. When I wanna get the Cookie, everything is fine in Android 4.0+ but in Android Gingerbread I've get a NullPointerException.
I don't know how to fix this, can anyone help please?

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){     
        String CookieValue = null;
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this.activity);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
        if(!cookies.equals(null)){
           String[] temp=cookies.split("[;]");
           for (String ar1 : temp ){
             if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
                String[] temp1=ar1.split("[=]");
                CookieValue = temp1[1];
             }
           }   
        }
        return CookieValue; 
    }
```

Here is the LogCat, it points on the `if`-phrase:

```
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan/de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity.getCookie(MainActivity.java:592)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:560)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1731)
01-26 17:59:22.789: E/AndroidRuntime(28108):    ... 11 more
```

EDIT: With Salmans code I've get this message:

```
01-26 18:35:04.050: E/Main Activity(28872): Error occured while Extracting Cookie Value !, Error = java.lang.NullPointerException   
01-26 18:35:04.050: W/System.err(28872):    at de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity.getCookie(MainActivity.java:633)
```

It refers to `if(!cookies.equals("")&&((!(CookieName!=null))&&(!CookieName.isEmpty()))){`

Comment: What exactly is line Number 592 in this method ?

Comment: `if(!cookies.equals(null)){` That i ment with "it points to the `if`-phrase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are passing an invalid reference of the Main Activity Object. 
However there could be many reasons for the crash. (Like invalid siteName/CookieName, etc)

Here is how you should modify the code, so that it would tell you what exactly is happening.

```
    public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){     
    String CookieValue = "";
    String cookies = "";

    try
    {
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity.this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if(!siteName.isEmpty)
        {
            Log.d("Main Activity", "siteName = "+siteName);
            cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("Main Activity", "siteName is empty");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Main Activity", "Error occured while getting Cookies !, Error = "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        if((!cookies.equals(""))&&((!CookieName==null)&&(!CookieName.isEmpty()))){
        String[] temp=cookies.split("[;]");
        for (String ar1 : temp ){
            if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
                String[] temp1=ar1.split("[=]");
                CookieValue = temp1[1];
            }
        }   
         else { 
         Log.w("Main Activity", "cookies = "+cookies);  
         Log.w("Main Activity", "CookieName= "+CookieName);  
        }
       }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Main Activity", "Error occured while Extracting Cookie Value !, Error = "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return CookieValue; 
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The WebView is only on my own page and the Cookies are there with the exact names and so on. I ran your code, the result is in the top post.

Comment: It has to be something with the Android Version, because on 4.3 I don't have that problem...

Comment: There was an error in the `if(!cookies.equals("")&&((!CookieName!=null)&&(!CookieName.isEmpty())))` condition, i fixed it like this `if(!cookies.equals("")&&((!CookieName==null)&&(!CookieName.isEmpty())))`

Comment: Theres still an error, the `&&((!CookieName==null)&&` must be in brackets like so: `&&((!(CookieName==null))&&`

Comment: Now it works properly, thanks alot man! But the actual code didn't changed, huh? Or is `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity.this);` the **MainActivity.this** the key, because I used `this.activity`...

Comment: My pleasure :) I already diagnosed that in the first line of the answer :) `I think that you are passing an invalid reference of the Main Activity Object. `